# Post data from angularjs to MVC action method which returns a view

Tags: angularjs, redirect, model-view-controller

I have a button in my view and on clicking the button i want to redirect to mvc action method with an object. The action method will then return another view which will then be displayed to the user.

This is the button

```
<button id="btnPreview" type="button" class="btn" ng-click="RedirectToBuyFlow(PreviewOfferId)" ng-model="PreviewOfferId">Preview Offer</button>
```

This is the function which is called on ng-click of the above button.

```
$scope.RedirectToBuyFlow = function (PreviewOfferId) {
        if (PreviewOfferId != null && PreviewOfferId != undefined && PreviewOfferId != "") {
            $http.post("/App/MockBuyflow/Qualify", PreviewOfferId);
        }
    }
```

The controller name is MockBuyflow and the action method is as below

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Qualify(string OfferId)
    {
        //do something 
       return(view);
    }
```

The problem is that it never hits my action method. However if instead of $http.post i use

```
window.location.href="/App/MockBuyflow/Qualify?OfferId=3036"
```

it works fine. But since i have to do a post request i cannot use window.location.href. What am i doing wrong in post?
Please help.

Comment: Did you check into console of browser whether $http module is assigned or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you just add the number to the $http method, it will just put it in the Http body for the request.

And ASP.NET MVC, won't know what to map it with, and will skip it.

Do this instead:

```
$http.post("/App/MockBuyflow/Qualify", {OfferId: PreviewOfferId});
```

By writing `{OfferId: PreviewOfferId}`

You are sending a JSON object to the server, and ASP.NET will know that you want to map that value into your `OfferId` input on the action.

---

I also believe that in later versions of ASP.NET MVC, you can use the `[FromBody]` attribute, to specify that the value can be found in the body of the request as follows:

**Javascript:**

```
$http.post("/App/MockBuyflow/Qualify", PreviewOfferId);
```

**C#:**

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Qualify([FromBody]string OfferId)
{
    //do something 
   return(view);
}
```

Comment: She cannot append in the url. She mentioned it clearly

Comment: my code is working but at end where we are return(view) this is not loading my view

Comment: I guess this won't work because of the callback then() that $http has..you have to return back to the same page and so the other view will not be rendered.

Comment: @GurunathRao The scenario you're edging out, has nothing to do with my answer, or the original question. If you're having issues, consider creating a new question. This question was strictly about why the parameter being sent, was not picked up in the ASP.NET Controller. The $q promise library or $http use of it has nothing to do with that.